# array to multidimensional object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a dynamic array for examples:

`var myarray = ['country','state','city','town']` or

`var myarray = ['country','state']` or

`var myarray = ['country','state','city']`

How to convert it to

`var myobject = country['state']['city']['town']` or

`var myobject = country['state']` or

`var myobject = country['state']['city']`

because finally I will assign a value to the object for example `country['state']['city']['town'] = 'some small town in Italy'` etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Array.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to create such an object:

```js
var myarray = ['country','state','city','town'];
const obj = myarray.reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({ [cur]: acc }), 'some small town in Italy');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of recursion will take care of that for you:

```js
const array = ['country','state','city','town'];
const fn = ([first, ...rest]) => ({ [first]: rest.length ? fn(rest) : null });

console.log(fn(array));
```